# returns 'undefined variable' even the variable is exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to do something like a auto suggestion, see below codes.

```
//search suggestion base on the string criteria given
public function search_tag(Request $request){
    $tags = tags::where(function($query){
        foreach(item_tags::where('item_id',$request->item_id)->get() as $i){ //this is the line 192
            $query->orWhere('tag_id','!=',$i->tag_id);
        }
    })->where('tag_name','LIKE','%'.$request->ss.'%')->get();

    return response()->json([ 'success' => true, 'tags' => $tags, 'ss' => $request->ss ]);

}
```

but it throws me this error

> ErrorException in ItemsController.php line 192: Undefined variable:
>   request

As you can see there is a '$request' variable

```
public function search_tag(Request $request){
```

but why it tells me that 'request' variable is undefined? any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **where** closure you're using **$request** which is not available, so you need to pass **$request** via **use** method

```
public function search_tag(Request $request){
    $tags = tags::where(function($query) use ($request) {
        foreach(item_tags::where('item_id',$request->item_id)->get() as $i){ //this is the line 192
            $query->orWhere('tag_id','!=',$i->tag_id);
        }
    })->where('tag_name','LIKE','%'.$request->ss.'%')->get();

    return response()->json([ 'success' => true, 'tags' => $tags, 'ss' => $request->ss ]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `$request` variable into the closure:

```
where(function($query) use ($request) {
```

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 1):

It's a closure and the request is not known in this scope, try following:

```
    //search suggestion base on the string criteria given
    public function search_tag(Request $request) use ($request){
        $tags = tags::where(function($query) use {
            foreach(item_tags::where('item_id',$request->item_id)->get() as $i){ //this is the line 192
                $query->orWhere('tag_id','!=',$i->tag_id);
            }
        })->where('tag_name','LIKE','%'.$request->ss.'%')->get();

        return response()->json([ 'success' => true, 'tags' => $tags, 'ss' => $request->ss ]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In closure if you want to use variable then you have to write within use().

```
$tags = tags::where(function($query) use ($request){
    foreach(item_tags::where('item_id',$request->item_id)->get() as $i){ //this is the line 192
        $query->orWhere('tag_id','!=',$i->tag_id);
    }
})->where('tag_name','LIKE','%'.$request->ss.'%')->get();
```